# Como definir string mas largo SIN USAR METODOS en JS

Tags: javascript, array, string

```
var animals = ['carnivores', 'herbivores', 'omnivores'];
animals[0] = ['lion', 'shark', 'wolve', 'puma', 'snake'];
animals[1] = ['elephant', 'giraffe', 'gacelle', 'hippo', 'koala'];
animals[2] = ['human', 'monkey', 'dog', 'bear', 'pig'];
```

tengo que determinar cuál es el string mas largo de cada cadena y luego realizar un array nuevo con ellas. NO SE PUEDEN UTILIZAR METODOS, simplemente con Loops. Estoy algo perdido porque mi lógica me lleva a usar algún método. Se que es más simple de lo que creo.

Cómo puedo hacer para no recurrir a ningún método??

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Saludos

Comment: Tienes una matriz bidimensional de strings: usa un bucle para recorrer `animals`, y dentro usa otro bucle para recorrer cada array de strings, quedándote en en cada paso con el string más largo encontrado hasta el momento.

Comment: Claro, pero cómo genero que vaya guardando la mas larga encontrada? ahi es donde me freno. Estoy arrancando a estudiar esto y creo que necesito desarrollar a fondo la lógica. Muchas gracias

Comment: Ten una variable temporal donde guardas el string más largo encontrado hasta el momento. Empieza con `let max='';` y ve comparando longitudes

Comment: Bien, entiendo lo de las variables auxiliares. Pero bajo que parámetro le indico al segundo bucle que compruebe si el string que esta iterando es más largo que el anterior?

Comment: Para i entre 0 y 2, tienes que `animals[i]` es un array de strings, así que tendrás que recorrerlo también: `animals[i][j]` con j valiendo de 0 a `animals[i].length` tendrá los strings

Comment: Muchas gracias Pablo!

Answer (score 0):

Usando únicamente `for` sería algo así:

```js
var animals = ['carnivores', 'herbivores', 'omnivores'];
animals[0] = ['lion', 'shark', 'wolve', 'puma', 'snake'];
animals[1] = ['elephant', 'giraffe', 'gacelle', 'hippo', 'koala'];
animals[2] = ['human', 'monkey', 'dog', 'bear', 'pig'];

let max = 0;
let index = 0;
let maxAnimals = [];

for (let i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {//<-- Primer nivel

  for (let j = 0; j < animals[i].length; j++) {//<-- Segundo nivel

    if (animals[i][j].length > max) {//<-- Chequeamos el largo de la cadena  

      max = animals[i][j].length;
      index = j;
      
    }

  }

  maxAnimals.push(animals[i][index]);//<-- Siempre va a ser el primer mayor o el único de cada primer nivel 
  index = 0;
  max = 0;

}

console.log(maxAnimals);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta!